# Meaning of $x∈ℝ^d$ notation in matrix approach to regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, notation

How does one interpret the $x ∈ ℝ^d$ in the context of regression, see below

[image]in the following context:

I understand the `d` refers the dimension of the x vector, but I don't get what this notation tells me. Note that I am not familiar with linear algebra, which may explain my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mathematically, your understanding is correct, $d$ is the dimension of the vector $x$ and so $x$ exists in the real space of dimension $d$ denoted as $\mathbb{R}^d$. By real space we mean the elements of $x$ are all real numbers.

In the context of regression, consider the simple case of $d=1$. Let's say we have a linear model for a house price $y$ as a function of its size in square feet $x_1$. Then we just have the linear equation
$$
y = \theta_1 x_1 + b
$$
where $\theta_1$ and $b$ are some model parameters. Now let's say we want to add another variable, the number of bathrooms $x_2$. Then we can write
$$
y = \theta_2 x_2 + \theta_1 x_1 + b
$$
The more variables we add, the longer this equation becomes. So let's write it in matrix form instead. We can define the column vectors
$$
\mathbf{x} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ ...\\x_d
\end{bmatrix}\ \in \mathbb{R}^d\ ,\  
\mathbf{\theta} = \begin{bmatrix} \theta_1 \\ \theta_2 \\ ...\\ \theta_d \end{bmatrix}\ \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
So now we can simply write the linear regression problem as
$$
y = \mathbf{\theta}^T \cdot \mathbf{x} + b
$$
Where we've taken the transpose of $\mathbf{\theta}$ to compute its dot product with $\mathbf{x}$.

**TL;DR** Matrix form let's us write equations in a simpler form, otherwise things get messy when there are many features and many samples in the input space. The equation may look different however the underlying model is the same. Getting familiar with linear algebra would be valuable.

Comment: Thanks. Please me comment to the post by 'generic_user'.

Comment: It's more standard to write the error term as $\epsilon$ (rather than $b$).

Comment: Thank you. If I may, I would like to ask a follow-up question. How then does one interpret the following: Gaussian density in d dimension, where data _1,...,_n. Each _i ∈ℝ^. Why would each datapoint, _i, be represented by a vector of d dimensions?

Comment: It's hard to say without full context, but from what you've written, the dimension $n$ is the number of datapoints, and the dimension $d$ is the number of features in each data point. Using the example of house prices, think of each $x_i$ as a row vector with $d=2$ columns, the sq. feet and # bathrooms. You have $n$ such rows for $n$ houses, which you can use to form an $n\times d$ matrix. If it's still unclear you can post a new question with more details on the problem and I can try to answer.

Comment: Thanks again. But then, is there a way to figure out if the d dimensions on a vector refer to d-columns (column vector) or d-rows (row vector)? For some reason, I always thought of d-dimensions as d-rows, rather than d-columns.

Comment: You can interchange between row and column vectors simply by taking the transpose. There's no hard and fast rule that $d$ refers to the dimensionality of a row or column vector, it depends on the context. It's more important to understand what $d$ represents in the problem, and in both cases (row or column) it represents the number of features in each datapoint.

Answer (score -2):

It's needlessly pretentious.  They're saying that $x$ is a $N \times d$ matrix (N rows, d columns), where $N$ is the number of observations and $d$ is the number of variables.  The elements of the matrix are real numbers.

Likewise, they're saying that "y is in the reals" which is to say "y is a vector of real numbers."

I prefer the convention that lower-case italic ($x$) are constants, upper-case ($X$) are vectors, and bold $\mathbf{X}$ are matrices.  It gets harder of course when you get past two dimensions.

I think that a lot of people use pretentious notation in order to demonstrate to others how sophisticated their math is, probably because they're feeling a little bit of imposter syndrome.

Bottom line:  if you're confused, it could be because the author is really smart and knows things you don't.  More likely however, it's because they can't write clearly or are afraid that you'll understand them and see that their ideas are actually pretty simple.

Comment: At a quick glance this makes sense to me. But then I read the other reply to my question (by user 'sudo') and I'm confused. You say d represents no. of columns and 'sudo' says d represent no. of rows. This was part of my confusion to begin with.

Comment: Either way. The "transpose" of a matrix flips it on its side, switching the row and column indices. I suppose that I assumed one configuration, rather than the other.

Comment: The purpose of mathematical precision *is* clarity. We who teach this are obliged to familiarize this notation, and not belittle it. Yes, you *can* learn it. No it *isn't* particularly hard. $x$ is a point not a matrix in your description of the problem, so @sudo's answer is correct in spirit and content and in the extension of $x$ from a point/vector to matrix of points, which is the next thing to learn. You can do it! :)

Comment: @PeterLeopold that sort of attitude is commonly window-dressing on gatekeeping. Many people, in many fields, want to exclude people who haven't spent the time that they have in a given community, and they do so in part with thick jargon. Yes it is clearer to say that x is in the reals than x is a matrix, because you can preserve a notion if sampling and future data. But this sort of marginal improvement comes at the cost of comprehensibility to otherwise-smart people who aren't part if your club.

Comment: All the haters can go to $x\in (you know where)$